# 404 (resource not found) in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, http-status-code-404

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.util.Date"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Clock</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        The time is : <%=new Date()%>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

The code shows resource not found when i run it on tomcat.
The url is http://localhost:8080/JspPractice/Clock.jsp .
JspPractice is the name of the project and Clock.jsp is the name of the jsp.

Comment: see the mapping. share you mapping files.

Comment: How is your web app deployed? I.e. where is the `Clock.jsp` file located on your file system?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no error in this code .This is server problem. Please check the port no of server , which is by default 8080 . and restart the IDE .

Comment: If he is getting 404 (not found), then the server (servlet container) has been contacted, but it cannot find either the `JspPractice` webapp, or the `Clock.jsp` file.

Comment: write but these problem is absolutely server problem because I also faced this type of problem .

Comment: I feel Rakesh Raka is right there is some problem with the server(i tried running other jsp files but they are running just fine) but no error in the code(niether compile time nor runtime).

Comment: i copied the same code into a new jsp file and it works.So sometimes the server behaves like an idiot.